# Sql Command error on C# Winforms

Tags: c#, sql

Im trying to copy a table structure in winforms app in C# and i always gets the error invalid syntax which is explained below : 
This is my code

```
con.Open();
cmd.Connection =con;
cmd.CommandText="Create table temp as select * from Class";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

and the error statement shows Incorrect syntax near 'Select' and
Incorrect syntax near class.

Comment: What is your DBMS??

Comment: My database is MsSql

Comment: And which line of your sample code is winform related? Would you get the same error if you copy/paste the SQL into SSSMS? Hint - yes, your taggig and title are totally off. TOTALLY - you tag it as MySql, demonstrating ignorance to wards WHICH database system you use.

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
cmd.CommandText="Create TABLE temp AS (select * from  Class)";
```

Comment: Nope I already checked it. Then i got the error incorrect syntax near '('

Comment: My database is MsSql

Comment: @Arun_Ajayan Is it Mysql or other? You said it is MsSql... Is that SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot execute this query because the "Select table" has Primary key or indexes.**

try this:

```
    CREATE TABLE temp
    SELECT *
    FROM class
    CREATE INDEX index_column ON temp(index_column);
```

It is important to note, if the table has **primary key** you need to run another query "Alter table.." and set the primary key column of the table.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
cmd.CommandText="Create TABLE temp select * from  Class";
```